# Tunneling TCP ports through ssh without blocking

Tags: python, pexpect, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying setup a ssh tunnel via pexpect with following code:

```
#!/bin/env python2.4

import pexpect, sys
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -CfNL 0.0.0.0:3306:127.0.0.1:3306 user@server.com')
child.logfile = sys.stdout
while True:
    code = child.expect([
        'Are you sure you want to continue connecting \(yes/no\)\?',
        'password:',
        pexpect.EOF,
        pexpect.TIMEOUT
    ])
    if code == 0:
        child.sendline('yes')
    elif code == 1:
        child.sendline('passwordhere')
    elif code == 2:
        print ".. EOF"
        break
    elif code == 3:
        print ".. Timeout"
        break
```

What I expect is after password was sent and ssh tunnel established, the while loop exits so that I can continue processing with other business logic.

But the code above block util timeout (about 30 seconds) if ssh tunnel established.

Could anyone please give me some advice on how to avoid the block?

Comment: are you willing to use ssh key auth without a password?

Comment: thanks for your comment. use key for ssh auth is OK, but will this solve this problem? I am afraid the problem was caused because the ssh process not exits immediately after auth passed.

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest solution is to use ssh host-key authentication, combined with backgrounding `ssh` with `&`...  this is a very basic implementation, but you could enhance it to kill the process after you're done... also, note that I added `-n` to your `ssh` args, since we're backgrounding the process.

```
import subprocess

USER = 'user'
HOST = 'server.com'
cmd = r"""ssh -CfNnL 0.0.0.0:3306:127.0.0.1:3306 %s@%s &""" % (USER, HOST)
subcmd = cmd.split(' ')
retval = subprocess.Popen(subcmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stat = retval.poll()
while stat == None:
    stat = retval.poll()
print "ssh in background"
```

Finally, if you don't already have `ServerAliveInterval` in your `ssh_config`, consider calling `ssh` as `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30 <other_options_and_args>` to make sure you detect loss of the tunnel as soon as possible, and to keep it from aging out of any NAT implementations in the path (during inactivity).